# STM8S. Ошибка при конфигурации порта

Tags: c, stm32

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с решением проблемы.
Использую МК STM8S003K3, IDE IAR for STM8 (v3.11.1), отладчик ST-Link V2 (китайский свисток)

Код конфигурации PORTC на SPL:

```
GPIO_DeInit(GPIOC);
GPIO_Init(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_MODE_OUT_PP_LOW_FAST);
```

На ноге PC3 находится один из катодов LED-семисегментника.
На порте С ничего белее не разведено, кроме 3-х катодов для 3-x семисегментников.

При выполнении данного кода из отладчика, а именно, когда доходим до выставления значения на регистре DDR в функции GPIO_Init

```
/* Set Output mode */
GPIOx->DDR |= (uint8_t)GPIO_Pin;
```

```html
void GPIO_Init(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, GPIO_Pin_TypeDef GPIO_Pin, GPIO_Mode_TypeDef GPIO_Mode)
{
/*----------------------*/
/* Check the parameters */
/*----------------------*/

assert_param(IS_GPIO_MODE_OK(GPIO_Mode));
assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN_OK(GPIO_Pin));

/* Reset corresponding bit to GPIO_Pin in CR2 register */
GPIOx->CR2 &= (uint8_t)(~(GPIO_Pin));

/*-----------------------------*/
/* Input/Output mode selection */
/*-----------------------------*/

if ((((uint8_t)(GPIO_Mode)) & (uint8_t)0x80) != (uint8_t)0x00) /* Output mode */
{
if ((((uint8_t)(GPIO_Mode)) & (uint8_t)0x10) != (uint8_t)0x00) /* High level */
{
GPIOx->ODR |= (uint8_t)GPIO_Pin;
}
else /* Low level */
{
GPIOx->ODR &= (uint8_t)(~(GPIO_Pin));
}
/* Set Output mode */
GPIOx->DDR |= (uint8_t)GPIO_Pin;
}
else /* Input mode */
{
/* Set Input mode */
GPIOx->DDR &= (uint8_t)(~(GPIO_Pin));
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Pull-Up/Float (Input) or Push-Pull/Open-Drain (Output) modes selection */
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

if ((((uint8_t)(GPIO_Mode)) & (uint8_t)0x40) != (uint8_t)0x00) /* Pull-Up or Push-Pull */
{
GPIOx->CR1 |= (uint8_t)GPIO_Pin;
}
else /* Float or Open-Drain */
{
GPIOx->CR1 &= (uint8_t)(~(GPIO_Pin));
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
/* Interrupt (Input) or Slope (Output) modes selection */
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/

if ((((uint8_t)(GPIO_Mode)) & (uint8_t)0x20) != (uint8_t)0x00) /* Interrupt or Slow slope */
{
GPIOx->CR2 |= (uint8_t)GPIO_Pin;
}
else /* No external interrupt or No slope control */
{
GPIOx->CR2 &= (uint8_t)(~(GPIO_Pin));
}
}
```

Вылетает критическая ошибка **"Flash memory not accessible while core is running"** и МК по SWIM перестает отвечать (**SWIM Error - comm timeout**).

Подкажите, в чем возможна проблема?

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Не по теме, но ведь если этот вывод подключён к катоду, то режим должен быть Out Open Drain?

Comment: Тактирование на GPIO подано?

Comment: @maestro, спасибо за ответ. 
В данном случаем нужен режим PP. 
По даташиту не нужно отдельно активировать тактирование GPIO на данной серии МК.